# iOS8 Custom Keyboard Settings.bundle does not show up

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I added a Settings.bundle to the keyboard target. But when I add the keyboard in the settings, the Items from the Settings.bundle doesn't show up. I had it working once. But this was in Beta 4.

-- best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS8.0.2, the settings appear in the General->Keyboard section of the iOS settings app.
However, a bug in iOS prevents from reading these values.

The solution would be to create a settings screen in your containing app, and read/write the settings to the Shared Container, using `[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.your.group.name"]`

Note, though, that this solution requires the user to allow full access in the keyboard settings, which is currently not a very user-friendly setting.

Comment: Still not fixed in 8.1.2 it seems. :(

Comment: My solution was to create in-app settings

Comment: Yes, but I really don't want to require full access just for providing settings. That's just lame. Oh well, guess I'll have to for now anyway.

Comment: You can display settings inside the keyboard itself, as you can set the keyboard height in iOS8

Comment: Good point - kind of like Swype does. I'll go for the container app solution first. Seems simpler to implement, and it'll work during development at least. Maybe Apple will get it fixed before I'm ready for release... :)